# How to get the latest records with filter in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have three sensors that are sending temperature records every 10 seconds to the database and I have a problem to filter the latest records of the sensors and send them to the client.
So far I have managed to find a solution, but I did it in a more static way:

```
let weatherStationsVarna = await Data.findOne({ name: "Varna"}, {}, { sort: { '_id': -1 }})
let weatherStationsPlovdiv = await Data.findOne({ name: "Plovdiv"}, {}, { sort: { '_id': -1 }})
let weatherStationsSofia = await Data.findOne({ name: "Sofia"}, {}, { sort: { '_id': -1 }})
```

pushed the variables in an array and send them to the client. But I need a more dynamic way. For example, if I add one more sensor I have to copy-paste and I think is not a good practice

My question is if there is a way to filter the latest records in one query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an aggregation query,

- `$match` the `name` of sensors ar once using `$in` operator, this stage is optional and just for understanding static conditions
- `$sort` by `_id` in descending order
- `$group` by `name` and get first recent document for sensor

```
let weatherStations = await Data.aggregate([
  // $match stage is optional, this is for static conditions
  {
    $match: {
      name: { $in: ["Varna", "Plovdiv", "Sofia"] }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PpPC5aArfvt)